# Click on item to change background image of another

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to use javascript to create a "button" of sorts using hovers on li items that will change the background of another li item (phoneChange). The items surround an image of a phone with screenshots I'd like to change when hovering over the related li item. I've been looking for a similar example here and haven't been able to find anything that works for me.

```
<ol class="list-b">
<li class="firstPhone"><span class="title">First Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li class="secondPhone"><span class="title">Second Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li class="thirdPhone"><span class="title">Third Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li class="fourthPhone"><span class="title">Fourth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li class="fifthPhone"><span class="title">Fifth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li class="sixthPhone"><span class="title">Sixth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
<li id="phoneChange" class="firstPhone"></li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
.firstPhone{
background: url(../images/mobile1.png) }
.secondPhone{
 background: url(../images/mobile2.png) }
.thirdPhone{
 background: url(../images/mobile3.png)}
.fourthPhone{
 background: url(../images/mobile4.png)}
.fifthPhone{
 background: url(../images/mobile5.png)}
.sixthPhone{
 background: url(../images/mobile6.png)}
```

Comment: do you want the image to change on hover or on click?

Comment: working sample?? or fiddle please

Answer (score 3):

Add some identifying `class` to each "button" (I called it button for the sake of simplicity):

```
<ol class="list-b">
  <li class="button firstPhone"><span class="title">First Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li class="button secondPhone"><span class="title">Second Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li class="button thirdPhone"><span class="title">Third Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li class="button fourthPhone"><span class="title">Fourth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li class="button fifthPhone"><span class="title">Fifth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li class="button sixthPhone"><span class="title">Sixth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
  <li id="phoneChange"></li>
</ol>
```

Attach an event handler to those elements:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('phoneChange').css.background = this.css.background;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure CSS solution using undercover radio buttons:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background: honeydew;
}

input { 
 display: none;
}

.item { 
  cursor: pointer;  
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#target { 
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 176px;
  width: 300px;  
  border: 2px solid crimson;  
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  top: 10px;
}

#click:checked ~ #target { 
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/3jxqrKP.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#click2:checked ~ #target {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/23lydbM.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="click" name="click" value="click" />
<input type="radio" id="click2" name="click" value="click2" />

<label for="click">
<li class="firstPhone item">click A</li>
</label>

<label for="click2">
<li class="secondPhone item">click B</li>
</label>

<div id=target></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<ol id="phoneList" class="list-b">
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('firstPhone');"><span class="title">First Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('secondPhone');"><span class="title">Second Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('thirdPhone');"><span class="title">Third Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('fourthPhone');"><span class="title">Fourth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('fifthPhone');"><span class="title">Fifth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li onmouseover="phoneChanged('sixthPhone');"><span class="title">Sixth Box</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor.</li>
    <li id="phoneChange"></li>
</ol>
```

And the code:

```
<script>
    function phoneChanged(className) {
        document.getElementById('phoneChange').className = className;
    }
</script>
```

This code reacts to the mouse hovering on each item. To react to clicks, replace "onmouseover" by "onclick".

Comment: I tried this and it wasn't changing the background image but instead it was making each li have that background image (so covering up my text). I want the background image in phoneChange to change only (since it is an image, not text).

Comment: For LI elements, I kept them as they were in your markup code. If you don't want each element to show the image, simply remove the "class" attribute. According to my tests, my code changes the display of the "phoneChange" element. Isn't that what you want? Oh wait, I must change the code (if the class is removed)... Done!